Data validation reference provides value and not associated list values - VBA Reference Errors
It seems I'm running into a relative reference problem with the INDIRECT formula in the data validation section of my code.
I am trying to create a macro that will automatically update and format certain cells with data validation lists in the 'Lists!' sheet every time the value in 'Input!'A1 changes. REFERENCE IMAGE HERE
My code below works well for populating and formatting the necessary data validation cells in 'Lists!', however, the data validation lists are composed of the singular value of the cell in column A, and not the associated table items that share the same name as the cell in column A.
Ex. Using the picture for example sake,

Scientific_Name would have 3 options derived from the table named "Scientific_Name" (Deus, ex, machina) instead of the value "Scientific_Name"
Fabric would have 2 options derived from the table named "Fabric" (Yes, No)

Below is my code:
Sub UpdateDataValidation()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim inputVal As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim prompts As Variant
Dim validationCells As Variant
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lists")
inputVal = ws1.Range("A1").Value

' Clear existing content and data validations
ws2.Cells.ClearContents
ws2.Cells.Validation.Delete

' Define input prompts and cells for data validation
Select Case inputVal
    Case "Brown"
        prompts = Array("Name", "Scientific_Name", "Gender", "Species", "Count", _
                        "Favorite_Food", "Favorite_Color", "Favorite_Sport", "Favorite_Drink", "Date", "Option_1", "Option_2")
        validationCells = Array("B1", "B2", "B5", "B7")
    Case "Orange"
        prompts = Array("Color", "Fabric", "Style", "Quantity", "Length", "Width", "Area", _
                        "Supplier", "Location", "Distance")
        validationCells = Array("B2", "B4", "B6", "B8", "B12")
    Case Else
        prompts = Array()
        validationCells = Array()
End Select

' Populate input prompts
For i = LBound(prompts) To UBound(prompts)
    ws2.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = prompts(i)
Next i

' Set up data validation
For i = LBound(validationCells) To UBound(validationCells)
    With ws2.Range(validationCells(i)).Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""A"" & ROW())"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Next i

End Sub
I was hoping to use INDIRECT(A1), and that partially worked in creating a dropdown list with more options. However, every cell that is formatted for data validation shares the same drop-down list.
I'm extremely new to VBA and from what I know of Excel, this seems to be a relative reference issue.
I understand how the indirect drop-down lists work and have properly formatted each table to its associated value. It's just a whole new layer when you add in VBA.
EDIT ******
After doing more research and finding out some more about VBA, I think my best bet would be to somehow utilize the range that is the data validation cells, and subtract 1 from the column value. I'm going to look further in how to do that, but I think it is the answer.
EDIT **** SOLVED
All. Please refer to the following link for the solution:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-use-data-validation-conditionally/5919237d-47ba-4247-8575-caa8a14156cf

Formula1 should probably read:  "=INDIRECT(INDIRECT(""A"" & ROW()))" but I'm not sure if all the addresses and names are correct.

@MGonet, Thank you for your recommendation, but that didn't seem to work either. Each data validation list contains the singular value from Column A

Since INDIRECT has to know from which table takes the data, apply these steps to your sheets

Name all your tables as the Header of the table (A,B,CC ...)
Apply to cell D3 (the first drop-down) for Data Validation: =INDIRECT(C3&"["&C3&"]")
Drag down D3 till the end.

The VBA code will define the actual values for column C. If wanted you can assign the validation formula for the cells dynamically within the code too.

